# Panda's Read_Excel function stalling in Docker Container

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, docker, docker-compose

I'm running docker-compose that has a php front end for uploading files, python watchdog for monitoring uploads via php and pandas for processing the resulting excel files (and later passed to a neo4j server).

My issue is that when pd.read_excel is reached in python, it just hangs with idle CPU. The read_excel is reading a local file. There are no resulting error messages. When i run the same combo on my host, it works fine. Using ubuntu:focal for base image for the php/python

Anyone run into a similar issue before or what could be the cause? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed,

I wasn't properly logging python exceptions and was missing openpyxl module.

A simple pip install openpyxl fixed it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).